# How can I create a new instance of a class (specified by a string) and also use named arguments?

Tags: c#

How can I instantiate an object using the string variable className and also pass in the constructor parameters as named pairs? (I don't want the parameters to be order dependent, and I don't want to pass them in as objects and have to cast them to their original class)

```
string className = "ExternalApi";
Integration integration = getIntegrationObject();
Logger logger = new Logger();

// how to do new ExternalApi(integration:integration, logger:logger)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the parameter

```
params Object[] args
```

and

```
Activator.CreateInstance
```

Comment: So I already know how to do it _without_ named arguments: `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(className), integration, logger);` I want to know how to do it _with_ named arguments. I don't understand how your question is suggesting I accomplish this goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)

Please see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Would you explain how you would use named arguments with this method.